# JQUERY + update only empty <input

Tags: jquery

```
          $('input.metaTitle').filter(function() {
            $(this).val('ya');
          });
```

The above code finds all inputs with the metaTitle class.

I can't seem to update it to only select empty  fields. I've tried things like:

```
          if(!$('input.metaTitle').val()).filter(function() {
            $(this).val('ya');
          });
```

Can someone advise how to limit this to only empty inputs.

thx

Comment: Use this one

    if($('input.metaTitle').val()!="")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use...

```
$('input.metaTitle').filter(function() {
   return $(this).val().length;
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UBUFc/).

...to select them.

I think using `$('input.metaTitle[value=""]')` *may* be flaky as `document.querySelectorAll()` checks the initial `value` attribute I think. It also won't work if the element doesn't have a `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can check them like this:

```
​$('input.metaTitle').filter(function(){
    return $(this).val() == '';
}).val('ya');​​​​
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/TM8th/)

or you can use:

```
$('input.metaTitle[value=""]').val('ya');​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TM8th/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('input.metaTitle').each(function(){    
    if ($(this).val().length == "") $(this).val("ya")
})
```